# How to recover website after get hacked from an hacker

Tags: html, php, css

My website has been hacked by cuyber_cube vaishakh. Now how can i retrieve the all data and files of my web site my website is made on corephp.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked with your hosting provider to see if they made any backups PRIOR to your hack?

Answer (score 1):

For a much more thorough answer by the pros, see *[How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/q/218005)* on Serverfault.

A basic answer for amateurs and your situation:

1. Read through this answer
2. Contact your web host to let them know of the problem and ask for help with any parts of this answer that you don't know how to do yourself.
3. Download any existing backups
4. Change all passwords with your web host, CPanel, SSH access, and similar means of access. Don't bother change passwords of software installed on your website (eg. your CMS or other applications you have installed).
5. Create new backups of your website, knowing that this backup will contain compromised content. You do NOT want to restore directly from this backup.
6. Take your website offline temporarily.
7. Wipe the server and reinstall your CMS and associated plugins from scratch
8. Go through your backups and find content you can recover
9. Restore site content, being very careful about what you put back. Remember that there could easily be malicious scripts mixed in with your website content.

For more detailed instructions:

- MediaTemple. *[Recover from a site hack or compromise](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644830/recover-from-a-site-hack-or-compromise)*.
- InMotion Hosting. *[Recovering After a Hack](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/hacks/recovering-from-a-hack)*
- HostDime. *[The Ultimate Guide to Fixing and Recovering Your Hacked Website](https://www.hostdime.com/blog/fix-and-recover-hacked-website/)*.

Comment: sondra, please do not answer off-topic questions. This site is about recommending software – not howtos, manuals etc.

Comment: @Izzy: I figured it would get migrated to webmasters.SE or serverfault.

Comment: We have a rule: Never migrate to a target you don't know (unless the target site's mods request it). I'm not active at webmasters.SE so I cannot tell if it fits there, sorry.

Comment: @Izzy: Sorry as I am amateurs I don't where to find my solution I will take care now onwards while asking the question. and thank you for your advice

Comment: @DhairyaBhavsar no bad feelings. As a pointer: all SE sites have a `/help/on-topic` page you can check with before posting. And if that's still unclear, on their corresponding meta site you can browse questions tagged `[scope]` (just put that in the search box). Enjoy your stay at SE!